# App design problems: scroll and amount problems

Tags: java, android, architecture

I am new to StackOverflow and I am not totaly shure if this is right but I want to make an android app for my fathers company, He is the owner of a Bed&Breakfirst and he wants an app to keep track of consumptions. I planed an interface of the product list where all consumptions can be chosen like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5JhR.jpg

Now the problem is that we need to be able to add and remove products. otherwise i whold have done it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget46"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Button
android:id="@+id/widget47"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_x="267dp"
android:layout_y="2dp" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/widget52"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_x="266dp"
android:layout_y="43dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget53"
android:layout_width="253dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_x="9dp"
android:layout_y="10dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget54"
android:layout_width="251dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_x="8dp"
android:layout_y="50dp" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/widget55"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_x="267dp"
android:layout_y="85dp" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/widget56"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_x="267dp"
android:layout_y="128dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget57"
android:layout_width="259dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_x="2dp"
android:layout_y="92dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget58"
android:layout_width="256dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_x="6dp"
android:layout_y="136dp" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

But that can only be done if you know the ammount of products that you have. But wee need to add and remove products (Editing isen't neccesary.).

Also if we add to many products to fit on the screen I want to make a scroll option that can scroll trough all products like that.

Is there any way to do those twoo things or is this immpossibile?

Comment: This is usually done with a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

A1:

Use TableLayout (or GridLayout etc) and page change buttons.
(This is easier.)

In this pattern, table (in layout) has fixed count rows.
Set OnClickListener to next / prev button to update each cell (text views) text.
(ex: page1: product name of row 0 to 4 is shown, page2: row 5 to 9 is shown)
OnClickListeners of each buttons next to cell text views needs to be modified too.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_01"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell 01" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_02"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell 02" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_03"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell 03" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_04"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell 04" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_05"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell 05" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Prev" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

A2:

Use ScrollView that contains TableLayout (or GridLayout etc.) inside.

In this pattern, table (in layout) row count must be changed to suit your data count.
(Create/remove TableRows in your code and add/remove them from table)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_01"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell 01" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_02"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell 02" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

for A1 and A2:

res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_view_width">250dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use android listview or gridview, whatever suits you. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) is a good tutorial on how to use a list view.